# Is the isomorphism problem for amenable groups decidable?

Tags: amenability, gr.group-theory, decidability

Is it algorithmically decidable if two finitely presented amenable groups are isomorphic?

Or slightly different:

Does there exist a family of amenable groups (indexed by natural numbers) for which one cannot algorithmically decide if two elements of the family are isomorphic?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**EDIT:** The isomorphism problem for finitely presented solvable groups in the variety of all solvable groups of derived length $\le 7$ is undecidable. This was proved by Kirkinskiĭ and Remeslennikov (Kirkinskiĭ, A. S.; Remeslennikov, V. N.
`The isomorphism problem for solvable groups.' (Russian)
Mat. Zametki 18 (1975), no. 3, 437–443.). The Russian version of this article can be downloaded from [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=7672&option_lang=eng). The English translation is available [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBF01095444).

Unfortunately this **does not fully answer** the original question, because the groups in this construction are finitely presented in the variety of solvable groups but may not be finitely presented in the variety of all groups.

I would guess that one could use O. Kharlampovich's example of a finitely presented 3-step solvable group with unsolvable word problem (Harlampovič, O. G., `A finitely presented solvable group with unsolvable word problem.' (Russian) Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 45 (1981), no. 4, 852–873, 928.) to construct the family of groups you need. Perhaps someone has already done this...

**Second EDIT:** Indeed, this was done by Baumslag, Gildenhuys and Strebel (see Theorem 1 in Baumslag, Gilbert; Gildenhuys, Dion; Strebel, Ralph, `Algorithmically insoluble problems about finitely presented solvable groups, Lie and associative algebras. II.'
J. Algebra 97 (1985), no. 1, 278–285.), who proved that the isomorphism problem is undecidable in the class of finitely presented solvable groups of derived length 3.

In fact, in one of her talks Olga Kharlampovich mentioned that she can construct a finitely presented 3-step solvable group $G$ with unsolvable word problem that is Hopfian. Then the isomorphism problem among the quotients of $G$ by one defining relation is unsolvable (because $G/\langle\langle  g \rangle\rangle^G$ is isomorphic to $G$ if and only if $g=1$ in $G$).

Comment: @Hans: sorry for the confusion, my original response was wrong and it actually does not answer your question -- see the edit. However, I still think that the answer is negative for f.p. solvable groups. Kharlampovich's example could probably be used as a starting point. You should probably `unaccept' the answer, if possible.

Comment: @Ashot Minasyan: I also had somewhat Kharlampovich's paper in mind, and wondered somewhat, because it is often cited when it comes to word problem and amenable groups. So I thought you found an earlier reference.

But anyway your answer is indeed already helpful, as I am not necessarily interested in a finite representation but any reasonable indexing (second question, which is a somewhat unproper as one may always concatenate the index with an undecidable function).


Comment: @Hans: the new edit hopefully settles the question. You could probably email to O. Kharlampovich asking about the construction of Hopfian examples. She mentioned it quite recently -- in a conference in Diablerets in 2010. Her talk is entitled "Algorithmic problems in solvable groups, Part 2", you can google it.

Comment: @Ashot Minasyan: Thank you very much for your new references and further edit. Yes, this answers the question completely. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 10):

According to the diagram on page 31 of Chuck Miller's authoritative MSRI notes, the isomorphism problem is known to be undecidable for finitely presented solvable groups of derived length 3, and hence for amenable group.  I'll add further details when I have time.

Comment: Thank you very much. The reference you state can be downloaded here:
http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~cfm/papers/paperpdfs/msri_survey.all.pdf
I see..

Comment: Looks like Ashot added the details to his answer around the same time as I posted mine, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is to point out that the particular way in which you
have posed the second question is not actually the question you
meant to ask, for it admits a trivial answer, requiring almost no knowledge about amenable groups. Namely, you ask,

> > Does there exist a family of amenable groups (indexed by natural numbers) for which one cannot algorithmically decide if two elements of the family are isomorphic?

The answer is yes. Fix any non-computable set
$A\subset\mathbb{N}$, and then enumerate the groups you are
interested in $G_0,G_1,G_2,\ldots$ (assuming there are at least
two non-isomorphic such groups) in such a way so that the indices
$n$ of one of the isomorphism classes is exactly $A$, and use the
rest of the indices for the rest of the groups (or just some of
them) in an arbitrary manner. That is, we make all $G_n$ for $n\in
A$ isomorphic, and not isomorphic to any other $G_m$ for $m\notin
A$. With such an enumeration, the isomorphism problem is not
decidable, simply because for a fixed $k\in A$, we cannot tell if
$G_n\cong G_k$, because this would provide a decision procedure
for $n\in A$, which is undecidable.

For example, a similar argument shows that there is an enumeration $G_0,G_1,G_2,\ldots$ of copies of the two groups $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, such that the isomorphism problem is not decidable. Simply make $G_n\cong\mathbb{Z}$ if $n\in A$ and otherwise $G_n\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, for a fixed undecidable set $A$.

Of course this isn't the answer you or anyone is interested in,
even though it does answer the question you actually
asked. So the point is that you shouldn't consider such arbitrary
enumerations when asking decidability questions about finitely
presented groups, but rather you want to ask about decidability
questions for the more natural enumerations of the presentations
that arise from a natural indexing of the presentations, by means
of a coding of the syntax of the presentation.

Comment: I took a recursion theory class as an undergrad and haven't really interacted with "logic" type things sense, but one thing I do miss is being able to make constructions as sneaky as this :-)

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins: In group theory by decidability of such a problem we would understand the the algorithm takes on input two finite presentations (and not their indices) from the given family and outputs whether or not the groups given by these presentations are isomorphic. In this sense the isomorphism problem is decidable for any subclass of a class where it is decidable (the enumeration plays no role here).



Comment: Surely the point is that the OP meant a recursive enumeration (ie such a family of presentations output by some Turing machine). So it's really just a typo.  You don't need anything as fancy as 'a coding of the syntax of the presentation'.

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins: Thank your for your comment. I was quickly aware of this afterwards when I posted it. I answered already Ashot Minasyan: "but any reasonable indexing (second question, which is a somewhat unproper as one may always concatenate the index with an undecidable function)."

@HW: That's a good way to interpret it.

Comment: Ashot, I agree that is what we would understand, and what the OP should have asked, but my entire point was that he didn't ask his question this way, and because of this the question admits this kind of trivial answer. A larger point might be that when asking decidability questions, it is important to specify what the input is to be. He doesn't want the input to be an index in some comparatively arbitrary enumeration, but rather, he wants the input to be the group presentation. 

Comment: HW, every decidability question involves a representation of the mathematical objects as finite strings that may be input to the Turing machines, and this is all that I had meant by that phrase. So ultimately, the input is an index (the string). It can happen that the decidability of a problem depends on the chosen representation scheme. For example, consider finitely presentable *finite* groups. If presented as groups (e.g. by their multiplication tables), then the isomorphism problem is decidable, but if they are presented by their presentations, then the isomorphism problem is undecidable.

Comment: Joel - as the isomorphism problem for finite groups, given as presentations, is decidable, I don't really understand your example.

Comment: HW, thanks, you're right, that particular example doesn't make my point. But there are many other examples that do. One's choice of representation of mathematical objects can often matter when it comes to decidability questions. And the difference between having a computable group via a program enumerating its multiplication table or a program enumerating a presentation of it is a difference that affects decidability questions. This kind of issue affected answers, for example, to the decidability of infinite chess http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27967/decidability-of-chess-on-an-infinite

Comment: Joel, I take your point.  I suppose a better group-theoretic example would be the difference between having a fp linear group represented by a generating set of matrices or as a finite presentation---in general, there's no algorithm to go from one to the other.  (Though the isomorphism problem is unsolvable for both, as it happens.)

Comment: HW, thanks. And I see now that you seem to have abbreviated your user name; I am certain that you are plenty aware of the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Joel - yes, sorry. I'm not trying to hide under a cloak of anonymity; I'm just trying to reduce my MO google profile. :)